# Enable Logs in script

Tags: vbscript

I am new in scripting, I wrote below script to create folders on multiple computers and I need to create log file which show success and failure status of task.
Can some one help me.

Script :

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\CL_Repair\Computers.txt")

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
strComputer = objFile.ReadLine

Set objWMIService = GetObject _
    ("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
    errReturn = objWMIService.Create _
    ("cmd.exe /c md c:\CL_Repair", Null, Null, intProcessID)

Loop

MsgBox("Folder = CL_Repair Created on Computers")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for..  I have worked with Bill Stewart many years ago on some scripting items and he is a reliable resource..

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/52873f35-5d55-498c-949e-da8ceb1df980/vbscript-write-error-to-log-file

Two items of notice:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Is a line you would need to add to your VBScript.

Setup a batch file to run:

```
@echo off
ECHO %COMPUTERNAME% >> C:\Scripts\errors.txt
cscript C:\Scripts\myScript.vbs 2>> C:\Scripts\errors.txt
```

Now, this should trap issues seen and should log for you.

Ok.. You asked to have a list (text) list of servers..  Try something like this..  You really don't need the VBScript to do this..

```
:: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/servers_nt.txt
:: Check all servers in the list
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('TYPE servers.txt') DO (
ECHO %%A >> C:\Scripts\errors.txt
IF NOT EXIST \\%%A\c$\CL_Repair\. ECHO CREATING FOLDER \\%%A\c$\CL_Repair >> C:\Scripts\errors.txt
IF NOT EXIST \\%%A\c$\CL_Repair\. MD \\%%A\c$\CL_Repair
IF NOT EXIST \\%%A\c$\CL_Repair\somefile.exe ECHO copying somefile.exe \\%%A\c$\CL_Repair >> C:\Scripts\errors.txt
IF NOT EXIST \\%%A\c$\CL_Repair\somefile.exe copy c:\CL_Repair\somefile.exe \\%%A\c$\CL_Repair
IF NOT EXIST \\%%A\c$\CL_Repair\anotherfile.bat ECHO copying anotherfile.bat \\%%A\c$\CL_Repair >> C:\Scripts\errors.txt
IF NOT EXIST \\%%A\c$\CL_Repair\anotherfile.bat copy c:\CL_Repair\anotherfile.bat \\%%A\c$\CL_Repair)

GOTO End

:END
EXIT
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it will not show machine name on which script fail to create folder.

Comment: Added the ability to log the computername to the log as well

Comment: It will log machine name from where script executed, not machine from computers.txt where successfully created folder or fail to connect or create folder.

Comment: OK.. Next Edit..  I added the ability to ECHO the Computer Name from the TEXT list..

Comment: It's showing  machine names from computers.txt but not showing status where successfully created folder or fail to create folder.

Comment: There the second section of my response is all in BATCH script and will write out a log for you..